# Is there any statement in Java which "void" can participate in?

Tags: java, jvm

Is there any statement in Java which "void" (with small v, returned from a method) can participate in?

For example it seems it not even possible to do `voidMe() instanceof Void` where:

`void voidMe(){...}`.

(This is a theoretical question out of curiosity.)

Answer (score 3):

Yes - a simple method call:

```
voidMe();
```

That's a statement.

If you mean an *expression*, then

```
voidMe()
```

is still an expression too - just one where the result is nothing. From [section 15.1 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.1):

> When an expression in a program is evaluated (executed), the result denotes one of three things:
>
> - A variable (§4.12) (in C, this would be called an lvalue)
> - A value (§4.2, §4.3)
> - Nothing (the expression is said to be void)
>
> ...
>
> An expression denotes nothing if and only if it is a method invocation (§15.12) that invokes a method that does not return a value, that is, a method declared void (§8.4). **Such an expression can be used only as an expression statement (§14.8), because every other context in which an expression can appear requires the expression to denote something.**

The highlighted part basically states that the *only* use of an expression such as `voidMe()` is a method invocation. There's no "bigger" expression that can have `voidMe()` as a part of it.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, `void` is not a type or an object. Thus it cannot be part of an "expression".

Any operator or function in an expression would use its arguments as input. However, since void is not a valid type, and there is no object of type void, it would not be possible to evaluate the expression.

Thus, any void function must be a statement by itself.

You also cannot create an instance of `Void`, because "The Void class is an uninstantiable placeholder class".

Comment: `voidMe() instanceof Void` doesn't work because voidMe() doesn't return a value, so you get 'unexpected type required: reference found: void', at the first '(', before Void has even been looked at by the compiler. Regarding Void, the applicable reference is not Wikipedia but the Javadoc. It says the same thing, curiously enough, which only means that Wikipedia should have cited it instead of just quoting it without acknowledgment.

Answer (score 1):

I copied from [Java Specification §8.4.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.5)

> A method declaration d<sub>1</sub> with return type R<sub>1</sub> is *return-type-substitutable* for another method d<sub>2</sub> with return type R<sub>2</sub>, if and only if the following conditions hold:
>
> - If R<sub>1</sub> is `void` then R<sub>2</sub> is `void`.

It can be used by Class literals [Java Specification §15.8.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.2)

> The type of `void.class` ([§8.4.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.5)) is `Class<Void>`.
>   ...
>   A class literal evaluates to the `Class` object for the named type (or for `void`) 
>   as defined by the defining class loader of the class of the current instance.

Answer (score 1):

Void is uninstantiable and thus you cannot use its value anywhere. (Seriously, what would you want to do with nothing? How can you even have an instance of nothing?)

You can however declare Void as a type parameter. This is necessary if you want to use some classes from the java.concurrent package. For example, you need to declare a Future<Void> in order to submit a void method onto an executor service. In one place you can then ask for result, which will be of type Void. This result is always null.

Comment: For example to un-void it so that I can chain method call.

Comment: @JohnS What do you mean chain method call?